# AVG suspecting MSBuild and VBCSCompiler as viruses, blocking me from compiling in VisualStudio

Tags: virus, anti-virus, visual-studio, compile, avg-antivirus

AVG is suspecting that MSBuild.exe and VBCSCompiler.exe are viruses when I try to compile a C# project in Visual Studio. This has suddenly started happening.

I have added both exe's to the exceptions list but this does not improve the situation!

I can obviously just disable the antivirus, but this isn't a solution to the problem.

[image]

I've also tried adding exceptions to the Resistance Shield and Software analyser, but still the build is blocked.

Comment: Did you restore files from quarantine after adding files in exception list?

Comment: Check for an AVG definitions update. It is likely that this has already been reported as a false positive.

Comment: This is still an ongoing issue for me. I am keeping the AVG definitions updated, but every now and then it just decides to block it or suddenly choose not to block it.